# Handling "export X from 'Y'" when generating d.ts files

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I am using TypeScript to generate `d.ts` files from our existing JavaScript codebase which is annotated using JSDoc, as per https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/dts-from-js.html.

My problem is that the TS compiler (understandably) cannot handle some non-TS syntax which otherwise is parseable using Babel, specifically `export x from 'y'`, e.g.

```
export { something } from './somewhere';
```

This yields the following when emitting types:

```
app/utils/index.js:76:1 - error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.

76 export { something } from './somewhere';
```

I have tried adding the `ts-ignore` annotation, but it does not seem to work (I am using TS 4.5). I get the same error as above.

```
// @ts-ignore
export { something } from './somewhere';
```

Apart from removing this syntax (which is not feasible since we use it a lot), what would be the preferred way of solving this?

Comment: As far as I know `.d.ts` files should never export something, right? An export isn't a declaration.

Comment: @Webber yes, we do not expect the exports themselves to be part of the declaration, we just want to ignore the code which the TS compiler cannot handle since they currently cause the entire process to fail.

Comment: @Webber a `.d.ts` file that describes a module should export what ever the module exports. See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwgOwM7wGZwLxwBQCUOAfHAN4C+A3AFCiSxwwCeYwcAYjnOlAJbIA5nAA+cZAFcAtgCNgUWkA)

Comment: @csvan `export x from 'y'` is valid typescript (for instance see [this file](https://github.com/Olian04/better-logging/blob/master/src/api.ts)). The error you are getting is due to something else. Also, adding a `//@ts-ignore` to an export is a bad idea (even if it worked), because that would mean that your `.d.ts` files would not correspond to the actual code, meaning that the effort to generate `.d.ts` files was pointless.